# Delay at the end of a for loop

Tags: arduino

I've written the following code to light up a row of LEDs one at a time.

```
int ledPins[] = {7,8,9,10,11,12,13};

void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ledPins); i++) {
    pinMode(ledPins[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ledPins); i++) {
    digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(i, LOW);
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

The above works fine. However after completing the for loop there is a long delay (about 10 seconds) before it repeats.

Why would there be such a long delay? Is this expected or is it a problem with my code?

Comment: Is it supposed to blink all LEDs in sequence?

Comment: @JanDvorak Yeah it blinks each LED in a sequence, then there's the (unwanted) delay...

Comment: if `sizeof` returns the size in bytes and each `int` is more than one byte, you will blink more LEDs than there are.

Comment: plus undefined behavior for reading past the array boundaries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the function `sizeof(array)` return the size of the array in the memory, in bytes. and because `sizeof(int)` is probably not 1, you get a larger value than expected.

`sizeof` can be use to determine the number of elements in an array, by taking the size of the entire array and dividing it by the size of a single element.

so this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ledPins); i++) {
```

should be rewritten as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ledPins) / sizeof(int); i++) {
```

see:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof

Comment: @Jan Dvorak. Arduino is not "derived" from C++. It uses GCC, this is C++. If you do not believe this switch the IDE to verbose mode and watch the compiler doing its work. It is only the IDE that tries to disguise the C++ compiler by generating prototypes (and doing a poor job at it) and a library that will link main to you sketches such that you have setup + loop instead of main.

Comment: @UdoKlein sorry, I can't find my original resource now. Wikipedia and the tag wiki are both correct now.

Answer (score 1):

In this case as the array has a fixed size it's simpler to do this:

```
#define NO_LEDS 7

int ledPins[NO_LEDS] = {7,8,9,10,11,12,13};

void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < NO_LEDS; i++) {
    pinMode(ledPins[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}
```

Or move the calculation of the array's size into a variable and use that.

```
int ledPins[] = {7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
int noLeds;

void setup() {
  noLeds = sizeof(ledPins) / sizeof(int);

  for (int i = 0; i < noLeds; i++) {
    pinMode(ledPins[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}
```

Comment: #define NO_LEDS 7 would better be somwthing like const unsigned int no_leds = 7; The compiled code will be the same but you get type checking by the compiler.

Comment: With regard to the second piece of code it would be better to compute this into a constant. That is const unsigned int noLeds = sizeof(ledPins)/sizeof(int); There is absolute no need to make this a variable.